# SharePoint Online - Profiles Missing From Import Question

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile

When a user is finally removed from Azure AD, their profile gets updated in SharePoint as "Deleted" and is then moved from Active Profiles to "Profiles Missing from Import." Is it necessary to manually remove these or will they eventually drop off as well? And if they don't automatically drop off, is there a good PS script that can query this? I've been looking but coming up short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you manually remove the deleted users from SharePoint Online since their profiles can be kept in sites for a very long time.

You can refer to the link below for a sample PowerShell script to find and delete orphaned users:

[SharePoint Online: Find and Delete Orphaned Users using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/01/sharepoint-online-find-and-delete-orphaned-users-using-powershell.html)

Another document that might be useful:
[Remove a former employee.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/remove-former-employee)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that first link and see if there is a good way to autmoate this. I really don't want to continue deleting users manually!